# Regex password validation needs just one more adjustment

Tags: regex, passwords

I have an expression that is close to what I need it's just missing my "no adjacent number" rule

^.*(.).*\1.*$

abcdef1 is allowed
abcdef1g2 is allowed
abcdef12 is NOT allowed (but my current expression allows this)

The password rules are:

Cannot have adjacent numbers
The same number cannot be repeated anywhere in the password
No repeating characters anywhere in the password

[edit]I am not sure what language it is using - I can tell you I am testing it with what looks like JavaScript (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).  I am using it in a windows application (Tools4Ever - E-SSOM) that is for Single Sign on

Comment: Please specify the language. Regex implementations differ quite a bit across different languages and not all of them support "look ahead / behind".

Comment: Better question might be why are you not allowing those? Developers sometimes get waaayyyy too overprotective of their users at the expense of a quality user experience, and this definitely seems like that case. Look at most major implementations and you won't find anything nearly this strict out there. A combination of letters and number with a min length and a required reset every n-days should be plenty sufficient for almost all implementations.

Comment: I agree this complexity is ridiculous but it's for a customer that already has this complexity in place, so we are just trying to mirror it in the single sign on application - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm that this does *not* match:

```
\d\d|(.).*(\1)
```

It may be better/easier to not use regex to do this validation though, as checking a unique character list is pretty easy to do.  I'm also of the philosophy that you shouldn't put restrictions on what users want for their passwords.